# Messages with SPF Softfail Not Rejected

Tags: postfix, spf

I have set up postfix+SPF on our mail server. Here is my 
`/etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf`.

```
debugLevel = 3
defaultSeedOnly = 1
HELO_reject = SPF_Not_Pass
Mail_From_reject = Fail
PermError_reject = False
TempError_Defer = False
Reject_Not_Pass_Domains = aol.com,hotmail.com, gmail.com, yahoo.com
skip_addresses = 127.0.0.0/8,::ffff:127.0.0.0/104,::1
```

I have set `reject_unverified_sender` for various clients and sender domains using `check_client_access` and `check_sender_access`.

However, I get the following message that was not rejected. (I have redacted the sender and the recipient addresses.)

```
Sep 30 19:36:40 server2 policyd-spf[21248]: None; identity=helo; client-ip=202.212.75.207; helo=mail.saketoba.net; envelope-from=non_existent_address@gmail.com; receiver=me@mydomain.tld
Sep 30 19:36:40 server2 policyd-spf[21248]: Softfail; identity=mailfrom; client-ip=202.212.75.207; helo=mail.saketoba.net; envelope-from=non_existent_address@gmail.com; receiver=me@mydomain.tld
Sep 30 19:36:40 server2 policyd-spf[21248]: Action: prepend: Text: Received-SPF: Softfail (domain owner discourages use of this host) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=202.212.75.207; helo=mail.saketoba.net; envelope-from=non_existent_address@gmail.com; receiver=me@mydomain.tld
Sep 30 19:36:40 server2 postfix/smtpd[20716]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from st2383.nas811.p-tokyo.nttpc.ne.jp[202.212.75.207]: 450 4.1.7 <non_existent_address@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: unverified address: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.27] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5; from=<non_existent_address@gmail.com> to=<me@mydomain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.saketoba.net>
```

From what I understood from the man pages and online help, the `Softfail` results from `gmail.com` saying that it discourages use of the client at the host `202.212.75.207`. Is this correct? If so, why wasn't the message rejected right away?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the reason: the space before `gmail.com` and before `yahoo.com` in the `Reject_Not_Pass_Domains` line of `policyd-spf.conf`. After I removed the spaces, I get reject on Softfail with gmail.com. The `man` page of `policyd-spf.conf` does not mention this, but for "SPF IP Whitelist" (`Whitelist`) and "SPF Domain Whitelist (`Domain_Whitelist`), it mentions that there shouldn't be spaces in the comma-separated list.